# Splitting Payment into different accounts in WePay

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, wepay

I have a website that provides various campaign and donation for it. So requirement is however any user will donate amount it will goes to owner of campaign but some of percent of amount will credit to owner of website(me).

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Basic Explanation:

Guess, I'm a owner of a website and you are owner of campaign, now any of user will donate you $100, now 10% of this amount e.g $10 will credit to me(Owner) and $90 will credit to you ( owner of campaign).

Hope you understood it well, let me know if you have any question

I've also read about it in : https://developer.wepay.com/docs/use-cases/split-chained-payments, but it couldn't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WePay's API let's you manage this through the `app_fee` parameter on [`/checkout/create`](https://developer.wepay.com/api/api-calls/checkout#create).

In your case, you'd create a request with the following parameters:

- `amount` = 100
- `app_fee` = 10
- `fee_payer` = "payee_from_app"

WePay will charge the payer the full `amount` ($100), and then will take out the `app_fee` amount specified and split the transaction between you and the campaign.  The campaign owner will see $90 in their account.

Now the last piece to this is the payment processing fees.  Most payment processors default their rate to 2.9% + $.30.  Using the "payee_from_app" option means that the *app* (you in this case) will cover the processing fees and those will be taken from the $10 that you took from the campaign owner.

So 2.9% + $.30 of a $100 transaction is $3.20.  WePay will take that from the $10 app fee that you charged, and you will be left with $6.80.

There are several different "fee_payer" options and you should read the documentation carefully to understand each one.  The nice part about `payee_from_app` is if you are able to negotiate lower rates from the payment processor, you get to keep more of each transaction and there are no code changes that you have to do on your side to see that benefit.  For example, if your rate goes down to 2.8% + $.30, the merchant will still only receive $90, but you will see the benefit and receive $6.90.

To summarize.  If the transaction is $100, and you want to take 10% ($10) of that transaction for your website, and let's assume your processing rate is 2.9% + $.30, then:

- Money to campaign: $90
- Money to WePay: $3.20
- Money to website owner: $6.80
- Total Amount: $100